# Getting TypeError int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: django-views, typeerror, nonetype

<kbd>I am creating a shopping cart using Django.  I can add items from a product detail view but once I get to the shopping cart I can't update items.  I can remove them but when I update I get the above error</kbd>

I think that the form is not getting what I am putting into the function but I don't know why.  Any help or guidance would be really appreciated.

> [Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw1RM.png)
> [Add to Cart View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCpDC.png)
> [Adjust Cart View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esp0t.png)
> [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU7Xw.png)
> [traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA2xN.png)

Comment: Sorry I don't know why it posted like that.  I am creating a shopping cart with django and I can't seem to adjust the item quantity in the cart.  I can add and remove but when I adjust them I get an error as above.  In the Adjust Cart View function I have a variable quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))  I don't think my form is getting this but I have no idea why.  I have added images above to assist or I might just have to re-post for it to easier to read.

Comment: plz add urls code